# Unable to locate the specified class: Cache.php in codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I got the following error:

> Unable to locate the specified class: Cache.php

Here is my file structure:

```
//Path : application/controllers/Blog
Class Blog extends My_Controller
{
    parent::__construct();
}

//application/core/My_Controller
Class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->driver('cache');
}

//application/config/autoload.php
$autoload['drivers'] = array('cache','session');
```

I have tried both loader for call cache.  I can't understand what happened behind it.  Does anybody else have the same issue?

Is codeigniter 3.0.6 stable?

Looking for help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure that file name and class name are `MY_Controller` so you should extend `MY_Controller` not `My_Controller`. Spot the difference.

Comment: I have tested each things about miss spell.

Comment: Thing is, I have used same things in older version of CI 2.3 and its working fine. I have just changed the System folder in the new version which is create problem.

Comment: You have to check in change log of CI what else is needed for upgrade. Btw. CI2 doesn't require obeying ucfirst class names.

Comment: When you changed the system folder, did you update the index.php to reflect the correct $system_path?

Comment: Also, CI3 is picky about capitalizaton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's your case, but I'm using Codeigniter 3.1.0 and had the same issue because I was extending my library class with CI_Controller.

Wrong way
application/libraries/Text.php:

```
class Texts extends CI_Controller {
```

Correct way
application/libraries/Text.php

```
class Texts {
```